# Can anyone help with this question about finding the total distance traveled on a velocity time graph?

Tags: kinematics

[Question about a velocity time graph for a partical](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u9zKw.png)

Comment: Do you know the formula for the total distance traveled, when given a (constant) acceleration and initial velocity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Distance involves speed(and is always positive), displacement involves velocity(need to take care of the signs).

Here the graph is linear and graphically you have $x = \int_{t_i}^{t_f} vdt = \text{area of v-t graph} $ .

First compute the areas of the $2$ triangles formed.

> For Distance add both areas(no need to consider negative sign).
> For displacement, subtract the second area from the first (here velocity is negative).

Comment: Cool, Thankyou, i've got it now.

Comment: You're welcome!